# ElementNotVisibleException when Selenium WebDriver isn't full screen

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get Firefox with Selenium WebDriver to enter a search query into the search field on this [Boerse Frankfurt webpage](http://en.boerse-frankfurt.de/).

I can successfully locate the web element via `find_element_by_name` or `find_element_by_xpath`, which gives `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10768e490>`.

However, when attempting to **clear the field, send keys, or otherwise click it**, I get the error message:

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible
>   and so may not be interacted with

I am not familiar with this error since before when working with Selenium, so I'm at a loss what may be wrong with my code:

```
driver.get("http://en.boerse-frankfurt.de/")

search_string = "test"

search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='searchvalue']")
search_box.send_keys(search_string)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

---

**Edit:** The problem here was in fact that the driver window wasn't maximized to full screen. See answer/comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the search field *to become visible* and only then interact with it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://en.boerse-frankfurt.de/")

search_string = "test"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
search_box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchvalue")))

search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys(search_string)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: It waits for the visibility of the element until `TimeoutException` occurs. For the naked eye, the element is visible in the browser. Maybe there is a "hidden" element or such.

Comment: @Winterflags that's strange, it works for me as is. What if you would maximize the browser window before navigating to the page: `driver.maximize_window()`?

Comment: That solved it! Good find! I had actually set the driver to only make use of the left half of the screen. I would probably never have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("http://en.boerse-frankfurt.de/")
//make some wait here to fully load the browser.

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='searchvalue']").click()
search_box.send_keys(search_string)
```

first click on search box and than do sendkeys.